# .NET RegEx conditional replacement

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to convert text containing URL's into HTML anchors using Visual Basic in ASP.NET 2.0, so far I have this (which is working) but it only picks up http and https:

```
Regex.Replace(message, "https?://[^\s]*", "<a href=""$0"">$0</a>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

I would like it to be able to also pick up anything starting "www.", so I tried the following:

```
Regex.Replace(message, "(https?://|www\.)[^\s]*", "<a href=""$0"">$0</a>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

However, if it starts with "www." the first $0 in the replacement requires an additional "http://" to be put in front... and I haven't got a clue how to do it (or if it's possible).

Comment: I am not big on regex, but maybe you could add a check if it starts the right way; if not, fix the string first? Then go to regex?

Comment: I think you should use two regex replacements. One with https and one with www.

Comment: The problem with the 2 replacement approach is detecting when one has already happened, so you don't end up with http://http://www.  Unless there is a way to say "If the input DOESN'T start with http://"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Regex.Replace(message, "(?:http(s?)://|(www\.))([^\s]+)", "<a href=""http$1://$2$3"">http$1://$2$3</a>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you!  I have deleted my previous comment where I incorrectly said there was a fault with it.  The fault is if you're using javascript regex (which I was stupidly using to quickly test) in which case change the "(?(http)http(s?)" into "(?:http(s?)"

Comment: According to tests which I've done your correction doesn't influence the result, but maybe I missing something. Anyway it's shorter so I'm correcting the answer.

Comment: your original pattern was perfect for .NET.  See my amended comment above.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

Convert text containing URL's into HTML anchors and insert http:// or https:// if it isn't in the input string :

```
string input = "text www.stackoverflow.com/questions message";
string pattern = @"(http(?<ssl>s?)://|(?<www>www\.))(?<url>[^\s]*)";
string replacement = "<a href=\"http${ssl}://${www}${url}\">http${ssl}://${www}${url}</a>";

Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reponse, but it does not solve my problem... how to get the ${url} to start with http:// when http:// isn't in the input string